# How do I reduce the 3-finger-drag grace-period?

Tags: trackpad, magic-trackpad

I'm using a Trackpad and I like using the 3-finger-drag gesture. It has this handy feature where it keeps the "mouse-button" down for a short grace-period when you release so that you can re-touch (with three-fingers again) and it will continue the drag gesture as if you hadn't let go.

However, in some situations I get frustrated at having to wait for the grace-period to expire and the gesture to end, releasing the "mouse-button". The most common frustration is in editor programs where you draw a selection and then you want to perform keyboard-shortcut to act upon the selection.

So how can I change this grace-period, I think it's about 0.5 seconds, maybe 0.75, I would like to try with 0.2-0.3.